# Bootstrap form helper time picker not working on my mobile phone

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the [Bootstrap form helper: time picker plugin](http://vincentlamanna.com/BootstrapFormHelpers/timepicker/#jquery-plugins) and it's working as intended on my desktop browser. This is the code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="start_time" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start time</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="bfh-timepicker" id="start_time" data-name="start_time">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the result:

[image: clicked]

This is the result when I click it:

[image: clicked]

As I said, this works well on my desktop browser (Google Chrome). But on my mobile phone (HTC One using Google Chrome) the time picker is not working properly. I can click on it as in the first figure, but when I try to enter the time using the up and down arrows, nothing happens.

How do I fix this problem?

EDIT: Tried on my mobile phone using IE, still the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to work at all. The demo site doesn't work in Chrome on my Nexus 5. I'd suggest using a different plug-in as the developers obviously haven't got that one working very well.

Comment: @BillyMoat That's sad, I really liked it. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

Comment: I've used that one before, but it's only for dates :) I need an input for time, HH:mm style. @BillyMoat

Comment: Sadly it's no longer supported, but I found this: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker which suited me perfectly. Include this and your first comment as an answer and I'll accept it :P @BillyMoat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there seems to be little support using this plugin. I ended up using https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker instead.

Answer (score 0):

first change

```
.on('mousedown.bfhnumber.data-api', '.inc', BFHNumber.prototype.btninc)
.on('mousedown.bfhnumber.data-api', '.dec', BFHNumber.prototype.btndec);
```

to

```
.on('touchstart.bfhnumber.data-api mousedown.bfhnumber.data-api', '.inc', BFHNumber.prototype.btninc)
.on('touchstart.bfhnumber.data-api mousedown.bfhnumber.data-api', '.dec', BFHNumber.prototype.btndec);
```

thene find "btninc" and "btndec" function

comment

```
$this.increment();  
$this.decrement();
```

finely change "etInterval()" to "setTimeout()"

your code will be like this :

```
btndec: function() {
  var $this,
      timer;

  $this = $(this).parent().find('.bfh-number').data('bfhnumber');

  if ($this.$element.is('.disabled') || $this.$element.attr('disabled') !== undefined) {
    return true;
  }

  // $this.decrement();

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    var interval;
      interval = setTimeout(function() {
      $this.decrement();
    }, 0);
    $this.$element.data('interval', interval);
  }, 600);
  $this.$element.data('timer', timer);

  $(document).one('mouseup', {btn: $this}, BFHNumber.prototype.mouseup);

  return true;
}
```